# Saving to file in android

Tags: java, android

I created a simple map creator for a game and I want to create a save button that will save all the information of the level in the game files forever (so when they quit the app the level will still be there), I tried saving all the information in a text file, but I fail to understand how it works and how to work with the `FileOutputStream` and how to load later on the text file. Is there an easier way to save a level or more suggested way? and can anyone explain me how to save a text file and load it simply? Thanks!

Comment: you could use a SQLite database

Comment: A very simple way to save something to the filesystem is to use the SharedPreferences framework.

Comment: `I fail to understand (...) how to work with the FileOutputStream` what are you trying to do? Do you have code already?

Comment: and for the other part of your question maybe give us some of your code and exception

Comment: @njzk2 I do have code already, I'm trying to save a text file inside the app (so the user cant get the text file) and after it load it

Comment: So, I assume you have some sort of data structure that contains the information regarding the level, and you probably have a serialization system to get a byte[] out of your structure. Then open a fileoutputstream (see Context documentation), write to it, and voilà.

Comment: If you DO store a text file on the system, user WILL be able to find and modify it.  If you specifically want to avoid users accessing it, you should use another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not storing a lot of data, the best way would be to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Here, the data is stored as key value pair. It is easier to store and retrieve data using this.

e.g.

**To store data**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.commit();
```

**To fetch data**

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
String name=preferences.getString("name",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the SQL Lite database is that what you want to use, if you save your data inside the DB, you will (later if you are enhancing your appp) have the possibility to easy sync saved information with a server so the gamestate can be synced with other devices without using the DB and just SharedPrefs this is much more complicated.
I would also advice you to use [greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/) which is an ORM for Android so you don't need to write plain SQL code

Comment: I've never used SQL and I dont really understand it, won't it be just easier to type all the information on text file and load it?

Comment: not if you really want to create a useful game and as I intended use greendao then you can work with entities and don't have to write annoying plain SQL code

Comment: Nickolaus is right. But if you want to go down that road with text files http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html , but I won't recommend it. If you have just 3, 4, 5 values to store, SharedPreferences, like arol_123 already mentioned is what you want.

Comment: @Nickolaus if so, do I need to download MYSQL and learn how to use it? is it complicated? I dont need to write more information than where is each block and how many blocks there are..

Comment: you dont need to download anything SQLLite is implemented into android as standard database, for see usage take a look at this site: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html but still, if you use greendao you don't have to care about SQL at all the ORM will compile all code into sql statements

Comment: Here's a good tutorial regarding SQLite for Android --> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html .

Comment: sry bro I was faster^^

Comment: @Nickolaus could you please give me an example of saving information and loading with greendao?

Comment: just take a look at the documentation I hav already provided the link in my answer but here it is again: http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to use Streams,

Inside your onClick method for your save button, you want to call this:

```
try
{
     FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("file_name.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
     os.writeObject(obj);
     os.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
      //handle exceptions
}
```

which will save whatever you defined in obj to a file named "file_name.txt".

To read obj back from this textfile, you can call:

```
try
{
     FileInputStream fis = getApplicationContext().openFileInput("file_name.txt");
     ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
     my_obj = (MyObject) is.readObject();
     is.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
     //handle exceptions
}
```